# aggregate values from one data frame based on another one

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, aggregate

I struggle with a big issue and I don't find an efficient way to solve it out. I have two (big) data frames with a common column like

```
#  DT1                   DT2
#  I  A B             I  C  D
# id1 1 10           id1 1  a
# id2 2 20           id2 2  a
# id3 3 30           id3 2  b
# id4 4 40           id4 1  a
# id5 5 50           id5 1  c
# id6 6 60           id6 1  c
# id7 7 70           id7 2  c
# id8 8 80           id8 2  b
```

the idea is to create a data frame which is the aggregate results based on the column D. so with a column AA which sums up the A values based on a,b,c, the same for BB and the last CC (the most complicated) sums the A if C is 1 and the B if C is 2.

Here's the results I'm trying to get.

```
#   AA  BB  CC
# a 7   70  25
# b 11  110 110
# c 18  180 81
```

I guess I need to use the `aggregate` function over DT1 but I don't know how to tell to base it on the column D of DT2. Maybe a `merge` but as I mentioned, the data are very big and a merging could soak the memory.

Any suggestion would be appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DT3 <- aggregate(cbind(DT1$A,DT1$B, ifelse(DT2$C==1,DT1$A , DT1$B))~ DT2$D, FUN=sum)
```

Comment: you won!! :) I'll check what ~ means by as it's out of my understanding

Comment: This assumes `DT1$I == DT2$I`? Is this always the case? There was an earlier answer using `merge` which is a better solution.